# preincrement postincrement precedence issues

Tags: java, operators, prefix, operator-precedence

I read somewhere postfix operators have higher precedence than prefix operator.

I tried this code:

```
int i=4;
System.out.println(--i+i++);
```

I expected the output to be 7 as I thought first i++ is computed and then --i

Result found is 6 so compiler is possibly evaluating prefix first.

Plz Explain.

Comment: Precedence would affect something like `i+++i`.  What you've written doesn't need to worry about precedence, just the definition of pre/post increment/decrement.

Comment: @Teepeemm plz elaborate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pre(in|de)crement happens before the command, by definition.  A post(in|de)crement happens after the command, by definition.  So your command is equivalent to:

```
int i=4;
i -= 1;
System.out.println(i+i);
i += 1;
```

Precedence comes into play when parentheses could change the meaning of things.  Since `(2*3)+4 != 2*(3+4)`, we need precedence to evaluate `2*3+4`.  Similarly, `i+(++i) != (i++)+i` (the first is `i+=1;i+i`; the second is `i+i;i+=1;`), so we need parentheses or precedence to evaluate `i+++i`.  But there’s no way parentheses could change `--i+i++`, so precedence is not necessary.

But as NutterzUK pointed out, any of these would be horrendous in actual code.

Comment: I guess if unary `-` had precedence over predecrement, then `--i` would always be interpreted as `(-(-i))==i`.  But that would make predecrement never occur, so there'd be no point in that precedence (or those parentheses).

Answer (score 2):

Here is what is happening:

```
--i makes i = 3.
```

You are then doing `3 + i++`

As i is now 3, and you have ++ after the i, it's `3 + 3`, then after this line `i` will become `4`.
So you are printing `3+3`, which is `6` and then changing i to become 4 (after).

Either way,.. why on earth you would ever do this I don't know, it's horrible to read.

However, for learning, you should try:

```
int i=4;
System.out.println(--i+i++);
System.out.println(i);
```

It should print 6, then 4. This is because when you have i++, you are using i, then adding 1 after. When you use --i, you are taking 1 off i, then using i. If you want to use i then take one off, use i--. Also if you want to add 1 then use i, use ++i.

Comment: I was just trying out stuff for exam . Best way is not what i am concerned about but just it should be right and error free.

Comment: Teepeemm made a point in his comment above. Could you explain the situation when precedence needs to be brought into play